# adding div to navigation - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In the functions.php of my Wordpress site creates the back/next buttons

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

    <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '<span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>' . _x( '', 'Previous post link', 'bnNav' ) ); ?>
    <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', _x( '', 'Next post link', 'bnNav' ). '<span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>'); ?>
```

...

which outputs

```
<nav id="nav-below" class="post-navigation" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-next">
      <a rel="next" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=369">
  </div>

  <div class="nav-previous">
     <a rel="prev" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=104">
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want to put another div inside each div inside the .nav but not sure how to add it to the code in my functions.php

I WANT the output to be

```
<nav id="nav-below" class="post-navigation" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-next">
      <div id="arrow-right"></div>
      <a rel="next" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=369">
  </div>

  <div class="nav-previous">
     <div id="arrow-left"></div>
     <a rel="prev" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=104">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

    <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next"><div id="arrow-right"></div>%link</div>', '<span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>' . _x( '', 'Previous post link', 'bnNav' ) ); ?>
    <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous"><div id="arrow-left"></div>%link</div>', _x( '', 'Next post link', 'bnNav' ). '<span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>'); ?>
```

Simply add the new `<div>` before the `%link`.

Comment: that does the trick, I was understanding my code wrong I guess, Thank you!